# Calculated Column with multiple If statement

Tags: sharepoint-online

I would like to have a column in which the date is calculated from the values in three other columns.
I have one column named "Last Test Date", a second column called "Type", a third column called "Insulation" and the forth column called "Next Test Date.

I need the "Next Last Date" column to be calculated so that it updates automatically when the "Last Test Date" date is changed, and basis the output value on "Type" + "Insulation" + "Last Test Date" values.

e.g.

- if "Last Test Date" equals 1/1/2021 and "Type" equals Winch, then "Next Date Test" equals 1/4/2021.(3 monthly)
- if "Last Test Date" equals 1/1/2021 and "Type" equals Cage, then "Next Date Test" equals 1/6/2021. (6 monthly)
- if "Last Test Date" equals 1/1/2021, "Type" equals Winch, and Insulation<=500 then "Next Date Test" equals 31/1/2021. (monthly)
- if "Last Test Date" equals 1/1/2021, "Type" equals Cage, and Insulation <=500 then "Next Date Test" equals 1/4/2021. (3 monthly)

I tried with below but the last two conditions it seems not reflected

```
=IF(Type="Winch",[Last Test Date]+90,IF(Type="Cage",[Last Test Date]+180,IF(AND(Type="Winch",[Insulation (MΩ)]<=500),[Last Test Date]+30,IF(AND(Type="Cage",[Insulation (MΩ)]<=500),[Last Test Date]+90))))
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Resolved with below code:

```
=IF(AND(Type="Winch",[Insulation (%)]<=50),[Last Test Date]+30,IF(AND(Type="Cage",[Insulation (%)]<=50),[Last Test Date]+90,IF(Type="Winch",[Last Test Date]+90,[Last Test Date]+180)))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Please use the following Calculated column formula:**

```
=IF(AND(Types="Winch",Insulation<=500),DATE(YEAR([Last Test Date]),MONTH([Last Test Date])+1,DAY([Last Test Date])),IF(AND(Types="Winch",Insulation>500),DATE(YEAR([Last Test Date]),MONTH([Last Test Date])+3,DAY([Last Test Date])),IF(AND(Types="Cage",Insulation<=500),DATE(YEAR([Last Test Date]),MONTH([Last Test Date])+3,DAY([Last Test Date])),IF(AND(Types="Cage",Insulation>500),DATE(YEAR([Last Test Date]),MONTH([Last Test Date])+6,DAY([Last Test Date]))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank youver much for this proper syntax :)

Comment: Hi, Steven. Thanks for your reply. Glad I can help you solve issue. Have a nice day!